# PuTTY Serial Baud Rate Settings Change on Already Open Session?

Tags: serial-port, putty

Is it possible to change the baud rate once the terminal has already been opened in PuTTY? If so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible: do so by right-clicking on the PuTTY icon in the top-left corner of your terminal window, and selecting *Change Settings*.  Then, choose *Serial* in the left menu and adjust the baud rate setting.